# text-align and text-align-last 'justify' with different directions not working properly?

Tags: html, css

The two identical code snippets, with the only difference being the direction, are displayed differently in the same browser:

```
<div style="text-align: justify; text-align-last: justify; direction: ltr;">
  <p>
    A B C D E F<br />
    H I J K L M
  </p>
</div>
```

```
<div style="text-align: justify; text-align-last: justify; direction: rtl;">
  <p>
    A B C D E F<br />
    H I J K L M
  </p>
</div>
```

In Chrome (Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (arm64)), some sort of indent is added to the first line (see just before the letter 'F'), screenshot ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rmXS.png)), but the correct line marking is applied when text is selected (i.e. from right to left).

In Firefox (Version 115.0.2 (64-bit)) the indent is not added, but the wrong linke marking is applied for when the text is selected in `rtl` (i.e. it's wrongly from left to right).

**Question**: How do I the get the desired result, that is as shown in code snippet #1, for all my divs set to `direction: rtl`  ?